# Fade in and out owl carousel effect not working

Tags: jquery, effect, owl-carousel

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
              navigation: true,
              navigationText: ["", ""],
              slideSpeed: 300,
              paginationSpeed: 400,
              autoPlay: true,
              mouseDrag: true,
              singleItem: true,
              animateIn: 'fadeIn',
              animateOut: 'fadeOut'
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Above is my owl carousel quote, i want to have the fade in and out effect but it doesnt seems to appear. Instead it appears as sliding effect.

Answer (score 21):

I don't think there is any option for fade transition:

```
transitionStyle: "fade" // not available in the docs
```

another option is to use [`animate.css`](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in conjunction with it:

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  navigation: true,
  navigationText: ["", ""],
  slideSpeed: 300,
  paginationSpeed: 400,
  autoPlay: true,
  mouseDrag: true,
  singleItem: true,
  animateIn: 'fadeIn', // add this
  animateOut: 'fadeOut' // and this
});
```

Comment: I tried and the effect came out as sliding effect instead,

Comment: if you could put a demo, that would be a help to answer it properly.

Comment: @user9437856 It is a delayed response but please find the updated link.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting would be which version you are using..
Your code example mixes up options from versions 1.3.* and 2.*.

Since version 2.* you need:

```
animateIn: 'fadeIn',
animateOut: 'fadeOut',
```

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

In version 1.3.* you need:

```
transitionStyle: "fade"
```

http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/#customizing

Comment: Links are expired

Comment: @Benjamin, Can you make a jsfiddle or code pan? because I tried but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

animateIn: 'fadeIn',
animateOut: 'fadeOut',

Will Work version - Owl Carousel v2.2.1

Comment: use latest version, and add animate.css and use these links to get more help https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/dev-external.html

Comment: http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/demos/transitions.html

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of  Owl Carousel(Version2.3.4) just use:

```
animateOut: 'fadeOut',
```